# Prevent starting a program if it is already running and has opened a particular file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to restrict a `a_command myfile` couple to only one instance.

- In my particular case I run

  ```
  qemu-system-x86_64 [options] -drive file=myfile.img,format=raw
  ```
- The script should check whether both `qemu-system-x86_64` is running *and* the file `myfile.img` is open. I think it is safer to prevent running if `myfile.img` is rw-open by any program.

How can I do that?

Comment: [QEMU performs its own locking by default](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/images.html#disk-image-file-locking), have you checked that you actually can start multiple instances in parallel using the same image?

Comment: right, qemu already performs its own lock. But i need anyway such a script. I've often needed it for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

While Stephen Kitt noted in a comment that this is likely unnecessary in the first place, you can still perform a check whether a particular binary is running and a particular file is open by combining `pidof` and `lsof`.

- `pidof` will find the PID of a process running the program given as argument. It will return "true" if at least one instance was found, and "false" otherwise. The output is irrelevant here and suppressed by redirection to `/dev/null`
- `lsof` will list all programs that have opened a particular file. If at least one program has an open file descriptor, it returns "true", and "false" otherwise.

A simple check would look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if program is running and image file open. If yes, then exit right away.
if pidof qemu-system-x86_64 >/dev/null && lsof myfile.img >/dev/null
then
    printf -- "An instance of qemu is running and file 'myfile.img' is open. Exiting!\n"
    exit 1
fi

# If at least one is not the case, execute your code here
```

In a more sophisticated setup, you could check if it is actually the `qemu-system-x86_64` that has opened your `myfile.img`:

```
if lsof myfile.img | grep -q '^qemu-system-x86_64'
then
    printf -- "File 'myfile.img' is opened by program 'qemu-system-x86_64'. Exiting!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Note that using `grep` to check whether the program name is the first item on the output line requires that your program name doesn't contain characters special to RegExes.